# How to fit the flipped exponential-function in Excel?

Tags: fitting, curve-fitting, excel, curves

I would like to know whether it is possible to fit the second graph below in Excel with an exponential fit? Unfortunately the "Exponential fit"-button is greyed out and I can't choose this fitting option. The goal is to fit it in the form: U_R=U_0*exp(-t/RC) or rather in the equal form U_R=a*exp(-b*t).

I have already fitted the first graph with the same approach and it has worked out (I took into account, that for y=0 the Exp-function is not defined). Are there any singularities that I need to consider for the flipped exponential graph for the second fit?

I would be really grateful for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

> Unfortunately the "Exponential fit"-button is greyed out and I can't choose this fitting option.

You have some negative values and Excel requires all values to be positive.

#### Why is this?

Excel is fitting the following exponential equation

$$y = a\cdot e^{bx}$$

in it's linearized form

$$\log(y) = \log(a) + bx$$

For this to work the values of $y$ need to be positive.

#### Solution

In your case, if you want to perform fitting of $y = a\cdot e^{-bt}$ with negative $a$, then all the values of $y$ are negative.

So, you can perform this fitting in Excel when you multiply the values of $y$ with $-1$, which makes all values positive.

This is not gonna work if you have both negative and positive values (this might happen due to additional errors). In addition, it might be that your problem could be including an additional parameter $y = a\cdot e^{-bt} + c$. In both cases the standard fitting with Excel will not work. You can use some other software, or use the [solver in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040).

Comment: Unfortunately your recommendation doesn't work because Excel insists that all the $y$ values be positive. The basic problem is that the fit requires *three* parameters: the third is an unknown additive constant.

Comment: @whuber that's another problem that might arise. But in the problem here the model has only two parameters and is issue are that all values are negative. Switching the voltage positive/negative seems like a simple and reasonable solution.

Comment: I think I didn't explain well: you can add a constant to the negated values and get a good fit in Excel.  The issue is that the fit depends on the additive constant, which perforce is a third parameter in the model.  *Every* increasing exponential with negative second derivative requires at least three parameters (scale, location, and amplitude).

Comment: @whuber "Excel insists that all the y values be positive" that's exactly what I am saying and I explain why. The offset is another problem that might arise. But the problem here has only two parameters and the issue is that all values are negative. Switching the voltage positive/negative seems like a simple and reasonable solution. The exponential $y = a \cdot e^{-bt}$ can be an increasing exponential (if $a$ is negative) and has no three parameters.

Comment: I don't follow: in what sense does this problem "only have two parameters"?  The fact that it might have been *computed* using two parameters in the spreadsheet, or that the OP might (falsely) believe a two-parameter exponential family will work, doesn't imply it can be *fit* with a two-parameter exponential family!

Comment: @whuber these are graphs of charging and discharge which are most likely gonna end up at a zero potential. The model for that can be a simple exponential fit (you are right, there might be more to it and maybe some offset is necessary). The main problem that the OP has is that all those values for the 'aufladung fit' are negative.

Comment: You can see in the entladung fit a very thin blue line for the exponential fit without additional offset and it seems to work well.